# Не работает общий буфер обмена между виртуальной машиной и компьютером

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

Установил VBox на Windows 11. Создал машину с kali-linux. Но обнаружилась проблема с перетаскиванием файлов из гостевой ОС в основную. Прогуглив данную проблему я наткнулся на решение, которое, почему - то, у меня не работает. Вот список последовательных команд:

sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

sudo chmod +x VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

reboot

Если 1,2 и 4 всё хорошо, то при запуске 3 команды виртуальная машина стала вести себя не так, как у людей из туториалов. Версия VBox: 7.0.14. Прикладываю скриншоты настроек и результатов из командной строки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]